# Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

at the time of running titanium application i am getting error, i have tried all the solutions suggested by google, but problem still remains, please help if anyone can understand the error log i pasted below. Thanks.

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 4.1.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
TRACE  | __command__ search paths:
[
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\.appcelerator\\install\\4.1.2\\package",
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\.appcelerator\\install\\4.1.2\\package\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\node_modules",
  "C:\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\.appcelerator\\.npm\\lib\\node_modules"
]
DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\appc.js
DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 623ms C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\appc.js
DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 2ms C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\node_modules\arrow\appc.js
log level set to "trace"
executing command "run"
set environment to {"registry":"https://software.appcelerator.com","security":"https://security.appcelerator.com","baseurl":"https://platform.appcelerator.com"}
checking credentials for existing session
Attempting to load session info from config file
check if session is invalidated
session expiry 1439531789135 false
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ This is a Developer trial account. You may use this software for evaluation purposes. +
+ Once you are ready to go to production, upgrade at https://billing.appcelerator.com   +
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Arrow Cloud config file: C:\Users\acer\.acs
found Arrow Cloud login { mid: 'dfa5b79881cc650462ff93ae5df5f65d5760e1cd',
  publishPort: 443,
  publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
  username: 'mymail',
  cookie: [ 'connect.sid=s%3Ab9eP%2F3NylwuSkAqEtFC3La1k.RDNuz84uHznd9QjZUQ9Rm6UxHfan0GZcGKug2GtaQjg; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 14 Aug 2015 05:56:35 GMT; HttpOnly' ],
  defaultEP: 
   { publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
     publishPort: 443 } } , checking nodeACSEndpoint= https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com
Arrow Cloud cookie expiry [ 1439531795000 ]
session already loaded in opts.session
getCredentials() session:
{
  "ipaddress": "192.168.1.13",
  "username": "mymail",
  "password": "<OMITTED>",
  "session": "<OMITTED>",
  "nonce": "<OMITTED>",
  "environment": {
    "name": "production",
    "isProduction": true,
    "acsBaseUrl": "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "acsAuthBaseUrl": "https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "nodeACSEndpoint": "https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com"
  },
  "token": "<OMITTED>",
  "fingerprint": "dfa5b79881cc650462ff93ae5df5f65d5760e1cd",
  "fingerprint_description": "Windows Machine ID: bcd68e35-cc53-4567-ab68-66246b73cc67",
  "org_id": 100057656,
  "expiry": 1439531789135
}
loading plugins for command "run"
run search paths:
[
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\.appcelerator\\install\\4.1.2\\package",
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\.appcelerator\\install\\4.1.2\\package\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\node_modules",
  "C:\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\acer\\.appcelerator\\.npm\\lib\\node_modules"
]
[PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\appc.js
[PLUGIN-LOAD] 251ms C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\appc.js
run plugin: C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium
[PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\node_modules\arrow\appc.js
run plugin: C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\node_modules\arrow
plugin "arrow" failed its "when" function check, skipping...
loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via function
loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via array
Duplicate option "colors" for command "run", removing...
executing command "run" with the following plugins:
["titanium"]
TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
TRACE  | session expiry 1439531789135 false
TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1439447168501
TRACE  | "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\titanium\bin\titanium" config -o json-object
TRACE  | "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\acer\.appcelerator\install\4.1.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\titanium\bin\titanium" sdk -o json
TRACE  | checking for titanium, result:
 { activeSDK: '4.1.0.GA',
  defaultInstallLocation: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium',
  installLocations: 
   [ 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium',
     'C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Roaming\\Titanium',
     'C:\\ProgramData\\Application Data\\Titanium' ],
  installed: { '4.1.0.GA': 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\4.1.0.GA' } }
TRACE  | C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe [ 'C:\\Users\\acer\\.appcelerator\\install\\4.1.2\\package\\node_modules\\appc-cli-titanium\\node_modules\\titanium\\bin\\titanium',
  'build',
  '--platform',
  'android',
  '--log-level',
  'trace',
  '--sdk',
  '4.1.0.GA',
  '--project-dir',
  'D:\\Titanium WS\\ex',
  '--target',
  'emulator',
  '--android-sdk',
  'C:\\android-sdk-win',
  '--device-id',
  'Appp',
  '--skip-js-minify',
  '--no-colors',
  '--no-progress-bars',
  '--no-prompt',
  '--prompt-type',
  'socket-bundle',
  '--prompt-port',
  '62727',
  '--plugin-paths',
  'C:\\Users\\acer\\.appcelerator\\install\\4.1.2\\package\\node_modules',
  '--config-file',
  'C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\build-1439448105417.json',
  '--no-banner' ]
[WARN] :   
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 24 hours i get my project installing on my device. i am unable to get the exact problem but i want to share my tried steps to solve the problem.

1. I installed all sdk's one by one.
2. I switched my current work space and created new one. (old work space still gives error)

Now my project is installing fine, every time.

Thanks.